# How can I remove or change the color of the ant design table row hover?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm working on a project that we are trying to apply a theme switcher, but the table of the ant design have a default hover property that is is preventing us from completing.

I have a table, styled with Styled Components, like this:

```
export const StyledTable = styled((props: TableProps<IRoute>) => (
  <Table {...props} />
))`
  th.ant-table-cell,
  button,
  td {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text};
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.background};
  }
  span,
  svg {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text};
  }
  .tag {
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.background};
  }
  td {
    border-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.strokes};
  }
  span.ant-tag.ant-tag-green {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text2};
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.approved};
    border: 0;
  }
  span.ant-tag.ant-tag-red {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text2};
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.rejected};
    border: 0;
  }
  span.ant-tag.ant-tag-orange {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text2};
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.pending};
    border: 0;
  }
  span.ant-tag.ant-tag-purple {
    border: 2px solid #d3adf7;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .routesTable .ant-table .ant-table-tbody .ant-table-cell > tr:hover > td {
    background: unset;
  }
`;
```

The styling for this table looks like this:

```
export const StyledTable = styled((props: TableProps<IRoute>) => (
  <Table {...props} />
))`
  th.ant-table-cell,
  button,
  td {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text};
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.background};
  }
  span,
  svg {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text};
  }
  .tag {
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.background};
  }
  td {
    border-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.strokes};
  }
  span.ant-tag.ant-tag-green {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text2};
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.approved};
    border: 0;
  }
  span.ant-tag.ant-tag-red {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text2};
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.rejected};
    border: 0;
  }
  span.ant-tag.ant-tag-orange {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.text2};
    background: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.pending};
    border: 0;
  }
  span.ant-tag.ant-tag-purple {
    border: 2px solid #d3adf7;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .routesTable .ant-table .ant-table-tbody .ant-table-cell > tr:hover > td {
    background: unset;
  }
`;
```

But it is now working.

I saw in research that other people had the same problem and none managed to solve it. Does anyone know if it is possible to cancel or change the hover color of an ant design table?

Comment: background: unset!important;

Comment: still don't work